# HTML 5 outlines: why do these two examples generate a different outline?

Tags: html, outline

I wonder why the following two (pretty similar) examples generate radically different HTML5 outlines.

### Example #1

- Codepen: http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/ZYVEoJ
- Fullscreen: http://codepen.io/jmuheim/debug/ZYVEoJ

This generates the following outline:

[image: Example #1: Outline]

This outline looks ok to me.

### Example #2

- Codepen: http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/ZYVERX
- Fullscreen: http://codepen.io/jmuheim/debug/ZYVERX

This generates the following outline:

[image: Example #2: Outline]

This outline doesn't look ok to me: the main content is now part of the header!

The difference is one single `section` container around the "This is the main content" h1 tag.

Can anyone explain me the logic behind this?

### Update: Example #3

As pointed out in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133768/html-5-outlines-why-do-these-two-examples-generate-a-different-outline/29134561?noredirect=1#29134561), it is important to know that `header`, `footer` and `main` **do not** start a new section, while having an h-element of the same size than a preceding h-element **does** start a new section.

So the simple rule of thumb to remember is the following: **When having a `header` on top of the page, a `main` in the middle, and a `header` at the bottom, then each of them have to start with an `h1` (which starts the implicit section). Under those `h1` elements, you then can add as many other sections (introduced explicitly by sectioning elements [`nav`, `aside`, `section`, and `article`] or implicitly by lower `h`-elements [`h2` to `h6`]).

I created another example which (in my opinion) resembles a perfect HTML5 outline - which is also a 100% understandable to pre-HTML5 devices.

- Codepen: http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/Kwbdyg
- Fullscreen: http://s.codepen.io/jmuheim/debug/Kwbdyg

This generates the following outlines:

[image: Example #3: HTML5 outline]
[image: Example #3: pre-HTML5 outline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the whole point of `<article>`, `<section>`, `<nav>`, and `<aside>` tags ("sectioning content" in terms of the [spec](https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-section-element)): they define sub-sections of the larger document.

You say "the main content is now part of the header", but that's not what the outline shows - it shows that the `<section>` is a subsection of the main document (`<body>`), titled `<h1>Header</h1>`.

In your first example:

```
<body>
  <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
  <main><h1>This is the main content</h1></main>
  <footer><h1>Footer</h1></footer>
</body>
```

..the `<header>`, `<main>`, and `<footer>` elements don't affect the outline. *(There's even [a note to that effect in the spec](https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-header-element) - look for "The header element is not sectioning content; it doesn't introduce a new section.")*, so for the purposes of the outlining algorithm it's equivalent to:

```
<body>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <h1>This is the main content</h1>
  <h1>Footer</h1>
</body>
```

In your second example,

```
<body>
  <header><h1>Header</h1></header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h1>This is the main content</h1>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer><h1>Footer</h1></footer>
</body>
```

..the `<section>` element introduces a subsection of the first section of the `<body>` element, so it's equivalent to:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <section>
      <h2>This is main content</h2>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Footer</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

(I added `<div>`s to mark up the logical sections of the document implied by the outlining algorithm.)

So the outline for this is:

```
1. Header
  1.1. This is the main content
2. Footer
```

This might make more sense with an example from the spec:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>The Tax Book (all in one page)</title>
<h1>The Tax Book</h1>
<section>
 <h1>Earning money</h1>
 ...
</section>
<section>
 <h1>Spending money</h1>
 ...
```

produces the following outline:

```
1. The Tax Book
  1.1 Earning money
  1.2 Spending money
```

Notice that "The Tax Book" is the heading of the document, and "earning" and "spending" are subheadings.

See also [the article on HTML5 outlines on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document), it provides some background for the feature, which will hopefully make this all clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to read deeply into the provided sources, and I think, I got the point now. I have updated my question to reflect the specific points, and marked your reply as the answer.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim looks OK to me, but my knowledge of outlines comes from the two pages I mentioned, so you're as good an expert as myself on this topic:)